# Can I access Instagram insights if my users dont have a Facebook account?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I am well aware that the access token and Instagram Graph API is necessary to access user or media API. But what if a user doesn't have a Facebook account but has an Instagram professional account? Seems like a weird decision from Facebook to allow having Instagram without Facebook but only provide API's for Facebook users. I am I limited to only serve users with a Facebook account as Instagram login isn't a thing?

Comment: I am in a similar situation. Do you want to access data from your own Instagram account or you want people to login to your app and give you permission?

Comment: I only want to explore insights from my own business Instagram account, I am finding it very frustrating at the moment. It seems that it is not linked to my Facebook or something.

Comment: From other accounts, I am not sure why Instagram login isn't a thing. This has been the hands-down dumbest design decision from a company worth billions. Still haven't found a solution. And for you, I recommend that you just connect your facebook or create a new one and connect that one. It's a hassle but you have to